# How to group Year Counts by State on a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I downloaded a dataset that is currently like this:

[image]

So for every state, I want there to be a Year column (since there are various years) with their counts. So in the Location Column there would be several Alabamas to match to each state. I'm stuck on how to get past just creating a new column for year.

Comment: does using `df.set_index('Location').stack().reset_index()` get you what you want?

Comment: another option is `df.melt(id_vars='Location',var_name='Year',value_name='Data')`